# CRUD in controller or model in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, codeigniter

I'm a newbie at developing and now I'm very confused on something... When I make a **Select, Update, Delete, Insert** where is this code supposed to go? In the controller or the model?

I've always done these querys in the model, but I've seen some frameworks like codeigniter have something called **Active Records** that are actually functions like *get(), where(),select(), join()* etc... these functions go in the controller?

I've done research but I'm still very confused. Help!

Comment: Anything that concerns database goes in models.   [Codeigniter's doc](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html) - [Details about models](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html)

Comment: Apparently, your research failed to include the CodeIgniter documentation.  [These basics are ***very*** clearly explained in the **Introduction** section](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html).  IMO, you should read the entire CodeIgniter manual from start to finish including doing the [tutorial project](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html).  It's easy to read and follow and should only take a few hours.

Comment: @AdrienXL, while I very much agree with you, [the CI documentation clearly states that models are ***"not required"***](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html).  Therefore, I am voting to close this question as "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: @Sparky Ok since the basics are very clearly explained would you happen to know where should the Active Record functions be in? Controller or Model?

Comment: You still didn't [read the link I gave you](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html)?  It says this, _"Typically your model classes will contain functions that help you retrieve, insert, and update information in your database."_ AND it also says this, _"Models are not required"_ ~ So put them wherever you want.

Comment: Yes I did read it. Ok, then it doesn't really matter. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**The Model** will contain functions that help you retrieve, insert, and update information in your database.

I.E.:

```
function insert_entry($data)
{
    ...
    database operations
}
```

Where $data comes from a $_POST or whatever you get the data from

**The Controller** serves as an intermediary between the model and the view, this is where you call your model to **Select, Update, Delete, Insert**

```
public function insert_entry() {
    $this->load->model('some_model');

    $data['foo'] = $_POST['foo'];
    $data['bar'] = $_POST['bar'];

    $this->some_model->insert_entry($data);

    $this->load->view('some_view'); // Tell the user the data was inserted
}
```

Remember, this is an example and you should do some validations first